# Is it possible to draw a colored rectangle on a pushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want after choosing a color from the QColorDialog put a rectangle (as a preview) on the PushButton and change its color to the color which I have chosen.

The PushButton before choosing the color:

[image]

The PushButton after choosing the color:

[image]

**Is it possible to draw a colored rectangle on a pushButton,

and how can I do that (an example)?**

Comment: Sure it is. Check the button's paint-event and draw the rectangle.

Comment: @maxik: Thank you, but can you give me a simple example or a link explains how to do that?

Comment: see my answer :P

Comment: see his answer :P Joking aside, if you would have asked the internet using my information you would have found something...

Comment: It may also be possible with qt style sheet (qss).

Comment: @m7913d: Can you explain how the stylesheet creates a rectangle?

Comment: I think you can set the background color of the 'change' text in qss, but I'm not very familiar with stylesheets in qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom class derived of QPushButton, for example:

**pushbutton.h**

```
#ifndef PUSHBUTTON_H
#define PUSHBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>

class PushButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    PushButton(QWidget*parent=0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};

#endif // PUSHBUTTON_H
```

**pushbutton.cpp**

```
#include "pushbutton.h"
#include <QPainter>

PushButton::PushButton(QWidget *parent):QPushButton(parent)
{
}

void PushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPushButton::paintEvent(event);
    QRect r(0, 0, width()/3, height());
    r.moveTo(rect().center()-r.center());
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
    painter.drawRect(r);
}
```

[image]